# T-SQL, Common Table Expression to a temp table, then TRUNCATE, and INSERT from temp table. Reasonable practice?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, truncate

I have a stored procedure that via a series of CTEs builds a result set which is then piped into a temp table.

It then `TRUNCATE`s the existing table, and `INSERT`s the result set from the temp table.

I'm usually only on querying side, not the stored procedure. Just wondering if this is a reasonable way to drop & rebuild a table.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#factTSPOrderGoals') IS NOT NULL  
    DROP TABLE #factTSPOrderGoals;
....

<Bunch of CTEs>
...

SELECT * 
INTO #factTSPOrderGoals 
FROM CTE_Final

BEGIN TRANSACTION 
    TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.factTSPOrderGoals

    INSERT INTO dbo.factTSPOrderGoals 
        SELECT * 
        FROM #factTSPOrderGoals 

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Any SQL command clears all CTEs - thus that intermediate step of writing to a temp table. Feels both clean & kinda janky, so curious how 'reasonable' this is in general.

Comment: Why do you insert into `#factTSPOrderGoals` from `CTE_Final` - but then in the transaction, in your `INSERT INTO...`,  you're again referencing `CTE_Final` (but not `#factTSPOrderGoals` ....)

Comment: Why not truncate your table first? Then you can simply insert into it. No need for a temp table at all.

Comment: Per the others, simply directly inserting into your table would work just as well. If this isn't desirable so as to reduce downtime on the main table, you could also insert into a regular table rather than a temp table, and perform `TRUNCATE` followed by `ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH`, which should be nearly instantaneous (after waiting for statements to complete, of course).

Comment: @marc_s Typo!  I insert from the temp table. Fixed in code example.

Comment: @SeanLange That's a great point.  That's a better idea, thank you!

Comment: @SeanLange 2nd thought - if putting TRUNCATE up in front of the CTEs, then the entire thing (including all the CTES) is wrapped in a transaction.  That means a table lock could be in place longer, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Better idea per @SeanLange - just TRUNCATE first

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.factTSPOrderGoals;

...
<Bunch of CTEs>
....

INSERT INTO dbo.factTSPOrderGoals SELECT * FROM CTE_Final

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

And thus no need for a temp table.