# Is this code for rebuilding a data warehouse table, decent practice? TRUNCATE staging tbl > CTEs > INSERT to staging tbl > SWITCH TO final tbl

Tags: sql, t-sql, transactions, truncate

I'm trying to come up with a standard way I'll do full table rebuilds.

- I'll tend to build the datasets out of a series of CTEs
- I'm considering the use of a staging schema (stg), and ALTER TABLE...SWITCH PARTITION just as a good practice.

That said I'm inexperienced on anything backend.  Opinions or tips on the below?

**Edit:** Changed to take into account the improvements suggested by Jeroen.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE  stg.MyTable;

----
<All my CTEs that build the eventual dataset>
----

INSERT INTO stg.MyTable SELECT * FROM CTE_Final

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.MyTable

ALTER TABLE stg.MyTable
SWITCH TO dbo.MyTable

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: Hey, that [looks familiar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72295512/4137916). Being the one who suggested something like this in the comments, I would say that `ALTER TABLE SWITCH` is a great way of reducing downtime, but I don't really see the value in using a temp table in this case. You are inserting the data two times here, why not insert it into the staging table directly? Also, note that `PARTITION 1` is superfluous if the tables are not, in fact, partitioned.

Comment: @JeroenMostert

They're not partitioned. How would you write it without the superfluous 1? 

Re: temp table.  Hm, once any command is run, my CTEs clear.  But, I could put the TRUNCATE TABLE stg.MyTable at the beginning before the CTEs, then do INSERT * INTO stg.MyTable SELECT * FROM CTE_FINAL?

Comment: `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS stg.MyTable; WITH CTE_FINAL AS ... SELECT * INTO stg.MyTable FROM CTE_FINAL; BEGIN TRANSACTION; TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.MyTable; ALTER TABLE stg.MyTable SWITCH TO dbo.MyTable; DROP TABLE stg.MyTable; COMMIT;`. The `DROP TABLE` isn't strictly necessary but brings us back to the beginning situation. Note that this does get more complicated if your final table has indexes, because in order for `ALTER TABLE SWITCH` to work, the metadata must match (almost) exactly, including any indexes. Here it becomes more attractive to keep `stg.MyTable` around instead of recreating it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Re Parition, got it I think: ALTER TABLE stg.factTSPOrderGoals
SWITCH to dbo.factTSPOrderGoals

 | Why DROP TABLE IF EXISTS stg.MyTable, instead of TRUNCATE?

Comment: I only wrote `DROP TABLE` because you did that to your temp table. :P If you keep `stg.MyTable` around (which is convenient anyway, to ensure the definition keeps matching `dbo.MyTable`), you don't need to drop it of course.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Nice, that removes the need for a temp table, and that message about "why are you specifying a partition I'm ignoring that FYI" that SQL Server was spiting out

Comment: @JeroenMostert The TRUNCATE TABLE  stg.MyTable at the beginning, is completely unneeded, right?  Sidenote - do you know *why* the receiving partition must be empty?

Comment: It's only unneeded if you can safely assume the table is empty before inserting; I wouldn't assume that, something might have gone wrong. The reason the receiving partition must be empty is very simple: switching is a metadata-only operation because the engine internally just switches the allocation units between the tables -- the empty partition (table) becomes the full one and the full one becomes the empty one, which works because they have the same definition. Obviously this can't work properly if there are already rows present; in that case we must use logged inserts.